# question during burg configuration in 14.04

Tags: burg

when trying to install burg I get the following message: 
The following linux command line was extracted from /etc/default/grub or the 'kopt' parameter in grub legacy's menu.lst.  please verify that it is correct and modify it if necessary.
Linux command line:

and the 'command line' is blank.  I am using grub2 and /etc/default/grub consists of commented-out lines.  If I try to skip the line, I have to fix dpkg.  If I try to install via the software center it can't find burg even though I installed the repositories.

A final question: the number of burg questions is incredible.  Does it generally work well for people?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The command line in question was 'quiet splash'.  when I ran the software updater it showed the old grub line which was 'quiet splash' so i copied it for berg.

Answer (score 0):

You can click **< ok >** and move next as it is shown in this [link](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-burg-boot-loader-in-ubuntu-1304-and-linuxmint/).